# xcode 6.3 hangs when opening organizer

Tags: ios, xcode6

I archived my project for adhoc deployment and it got stuck after it said archive completed.

Now whenever I click Window->Organizer Xcode freezes up. I need to save my archive for adhoc deployment but it just won't let me. I've tried restarting xcode and my macbook.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16):

I don't know what was causing my xCode (6.3.1) organiser to freeze, but I manually cleared out the `Archives` folder and organiser returned.

`rm -rfd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/*`

If, like me, you have archives you want to keep, remove individual archive folders by date order as needed and then try open organiser.

`rm -rfd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-xx-xx`

Comment: I recommend doing this with xcode closed. It froze when I did this.

Answer (score 11):

I removed all of the archives in Archives directory but the Organizer kept on hanging.

If you have too many different products (mine are over 200), Organizer shows up, then the colored wheel appears and keeps spinning forever. Move most of the directories in the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products directory somewhere else, and leave the needed ones only. That fixed the hang for me.

Comment: Thanks that helped me.

Comment: I was fixing it by just removing the archives folder contents but now it doesn't solve the issue. Only removing the Products folder has solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this too and filed bug 22455581 on it.

Xcode 6.4 and 7b5 (I didn't try 6.3) do something with the archives when the organizer window is first opened after each launch. This something takes a bit over a half second for each archive during which time all you see is the spinning beachball of death and Force Quit declaring Xcode is unresponsive. So in my case with 7+GB of archives, had I waited a thousand or so seconds, the organizer window would have eventually popped up.

As answered above, the workaround is fairly simple: quit Xcode and reduce the number of archives in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives. Move them out to somewhere else so you can move them back in as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at apple forget to do stuff on the background thread,... They look into all your account that xcode has access to and than scans all the folders for files. Also it makes a lot of webcalls for each related project to get crash logs. During this process the entire main thread stalls until it is all finished.... You cannot really do anything yourself for it except complain to apple or try to keep the apps/accounts you use at the same time to a minimum (not a real solution...)